# Two triggers on one table sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have two triggers on one of the tables in my database. One is for insert trigger and the other is an after update trigger. The insert trigger will update the table with values. My question is this; Is it possible that that the update trigger is firing at the same time that the insert is doing its job?

Answer (score 2):

A `FOR INSERT` trigger will fire *only* on `INSERT` statements.  A `FOR UPDATE` trigger will fire *only* on `UPDATE` statements.  Of course, if your insert trigger executes any `UPDATE` statements then it will fire the update trigger, and vice versa.

Your `UPDATE` trigger won't fire for an `INSERT` statement (excepting the update-within-trigger case above), but of course you still have to design for concurrency, since it's possible for two different users to be running two different operations at the same time - one `INSERT` and one `UPDATE`.

Comment: Besides an `update` statement, a `merge` statement, or a background update by replication, can both fire a `for update` trigger

Answer (score 0):

If your insert trigger does an update to the table, the update trigger will be called.  If a trigger triggers another trigger, it's called a "recursive trigger".

Recursive triggers can be disabled for an entire server:

```
sp_configure 'nested_triggers', 0
go
reconfigure
```

Or for one database:

```
alter database yourdb set recursive_triggers off
```